# What's causing "NoMethodError: undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, methods, undefined

I have a Book model in my Rails application, with various properties (aka columns in the book db table). One of these properties is "ranking".

Recently, may app has started to throw `NoMethodError: undefined method 'include?' for nil:NilClass` for the following code:

```
def some_method(book, another_arg)
  return book.ranking unless book.ranking.blank?
  ...
end
```

However, it's not consistent. The vast majority of the time, accessing book.ranking works -- the error is thrown maybe 2-4% of the time. If I change the code to `book[:ranking]` or `book['ranking']` instead of `book.ranking`, it works 100% of the time.

Any ideas?

P.S. This problem has popped up intermittently with other models and attributes... not just Book and the ranking attribute.

Comment: That used to happen to me sometimes in the console after reloading the app. I figured out where it was coming from once, but I forgot. Somewhere deep in the rails code. I think maybe it's related to the mysql interface, are you using mysql?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL, and my app is running on Heroku. When I log into Heroku's console remotely, this error pops up all the time (but never on my local console).

Comment: I know this is really old now, but I've upvoted, as I'm seeing the same error relating to a method which checks `.nil?` rather than `.blank?`. It does not occur consistently, and a second run of the same code, or a page refresh, always seems to return to the expected behaviour. This only started happening when I switched the dev environment from SQLite3 to MySQL in order to more closely mimic the production environment, so I am inclined to agree with @mckeed.

Answer (score 2):

the book object is the one that is nil, not ranking.  So having

```
return book.ranking unless book.nil?
```

should resolve the issue.

Comment: If that's the case, shouldn't the error be `NoMethodError: undefined method `ranking' for nil:NilClass`?

Comment: Good point, I think I am wrong.  I am looking at http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2-3-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb, the method_missing (which is called when you call your ranking method) seems to call include? on @attributes .  Maybe this is nil for some reason?

Comment: I've encountered this problem:  it was nothing to do with the object being nil as many on this thread have said, but it was something going wrong inside rails.  "question.id" was causing a nil.include? error but "question[:id]" worked fine.  I think it is something with @attributes as Rob suggests but i can't pin it down.  Outputting "question.attributes" to the logger seemed to return totally normal results.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `try` here:

```
book.try(:ranking)
```

If `book` or `ranking` is `nil` then `nil` will be returned.

Comment: try works, but it is not in Ruby 1.8... You have to use Active Support to get it in 1.8

Comment: @severin: Given this is a Rails question I assumed that they already had Active Support used.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few ways to protect from nil-calls:

check with **if**:

```
return book.ranking if book
```

use **&&/and**:

```
return book && book.ranking
```

use **try** (in Ruby 1.9 or with Rails/ActiveSupport):

```
return book.try(:ranking)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should check if book is nil either

```
return book.ranking unless book.blank? and book.ranking.blank?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it also this way:

```
return book.ranking unless book and book.ranking
```

or with `andand` gem:

```
return book.ranking unless book.andand.ranking
```